# How to create a form dynamically in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, forms, ios4

Pre Assumption : Having template of quotation form in place

I am working on a use case in creating a quotation document dynamically with the edited data(collected within the application)  to be saved and sent it as a attachment through a mail.

So my queries :

1) Can i dynamically edit the fields of form/document within iOS SDK programmatically?
2) if 1 is possible , how could i save the edited document in the mail as attachment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create HTML forms dynamically or build a UIView subclass programatically, with dynamically created UILabels and UITextFields, which can be configured at run time to reflect the form fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean HTML forms? When you are programming in iOS, I would suggest you create your form in ObjectiveC using the constructs of iOS. This gives you advantage of leveraging Core-Animation, Core-Location & other iOS frameworks.

Once your form is filled (by some user). You can parse out the fields, & construct your own basic HTML out of these fields. This custom generated HTML can then by mailed using the framework [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

What I have told is not exactly what you asked for. But hope you see the advantages in the approach.